# Shading stock/date plot based on indicator

Tags: r, time-series, finance, indicator, shading

My problem is that I have some stock prices(numbers) that are plotted against dates(strings). Now I have an indicator variable. I would like to shade the area on the graph for those dates where the indicator is 1 and not shade when it is 0. I'm programming in R. I know how to do it for a prespecified interval for example 2000-01-01 to 2001-01-01. But I have many "intervals" where the indicator variable shows 1 and I would prefer not to count them myself. Any ideas on how to overcome this obstacle? I would like it to be through ggplot2 if possible.

Example of my data:

```
data <- data.frame(
   date = as.Date(c("2001-01-01", "2001-01-02", "2001-01-03",
   "2001-01-04","2001-01-05","2001-01-06", "2001-01-07", 
   "2001-01-08","2001-01-09","2001-01-10")),
   price = c(623.3,515.2,611.0,729.0,843.25,623.3,515.2,611.0,729.0,843.25),
   indicator = c(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0)
)
```

NOTE: I've asked this question before, but it got marked as a duplicate. I do not consider it so, since I cannot find any other post that actually answers my question. I've seen others with the same question, but the answers are always to specify your own range to shade, which it is not the purpose here.

Comment: You have days that are close together over a decade apart. You want these on the same plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that you need to *use your data* to create the shaded background areas.

```r
library(ggplot2)

background_df <- data[data$indicator == 1,]
background_df$end <- background_df$date + lubridate::days(1)

ggplot(data, aes(date, price)) +
  geom_rect(ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, aes(xmin = date, xmax = end),
            data = background_df, fill = "deepskyblue4", alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(colour = "orange3") +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! I realised that in my example I wrote 2012 some times but it should be 2001. I've changed that. I've tried running your script, but it seems like there is an error when your are adding 1 in the second line since the "date" is not binary.

Comment: @MarcAllan it works with your sample data frame - it's how I created the plot. Are you sure the column in your real data is in `Date` format? In any case you can probably change `data$date + 1` to `data$date + lubridate::days(1)`. Just ensure your date column isn't actually a factor or character vector - check `class(data$date)`